# Superimpose orthographic projection onto map in Basemap

Tags: python, projection, matplotlib-basemap, orthographic

On this [link](https://www.iris.edu/hq/files/programs/education_and_outreach/retm/tm_131117_scotia/131117_Scotia.pdf), page 4, you can see an orthographic projection showing the location on Earth inside a black circular border, superimposed on a regional map. I'd like to replicate the same. For the orthographic projection I have the following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(projection='ortho',lon_0=-105,lat_0=40,resolution='l')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='white',lake_color='cornflowerblue')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,30.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,420.,60.))
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
```

But then I'm stuck on how to get this map, onto the bottom left corner of another regional/local map. How do I go about doing this?